# Obter ficheiro armazenado em Bin no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, upload, arquivo, binary

Viva!

Estou com problema em obter o meu ficheiro PDF que foi armazenado numa BD MySQL.
Sempre que eu faço o download do mesmo, não consigo abri-lo porque retorna a mensagem que poderá estar danificado.

Assim eu armazeno:

```
$docs = new Documentos();

$assunto = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'assunto');
$origem = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'origem');
$dataEntrada = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataEntrada');

$fileName = $_FILES['ficheiros']['name'];
$ficheiro_temp = $_FILES['ficheiros']['tmp_name'];
$tamanho = $_FILES['ficheiros']['size'];
$tipo = $_FILES['ficheiros']['type'];

copy($ficheiro_temp, "../upload/$fileName");

$ficheiro = file_get_contents($ficheiro_temp);
$ficheiro = addslashes($ficheiro);


$docs->setAssunto($assunto);
$docs->setDataEntrada($dataEntrada);
$docs->setOrigem($origem);
$docs->setDocName($fileName);
$docs->setTipo($tipo);
$docs->setTamanho($tamanho);
$docs->setFicheiro($ficheiro);

$docs->armazenarFicheiros();
```

Assim eu faço o download:

```
foreach ($docs->verFicheiro() as $f){
        $file = $f['ficheiro'];
        $size = $f['tamanho'];
        $type = $f['tipo'];
        $name = $f['nomedocumento'];
    }

    header("Content-length: {$size}");
    header("Content-type: {$type}");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');

    fpassthru($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Está aí qualquer coisa estranha nesse código para o download. Estás a usar um foreach, mas depois só fazes o envio do ficheiro uma vez. Porque é que estás a fazer um foreach?

Para além disso, o que é que é esse Documentos? Uma class tua? Ou de uma API externa? Falta muita informação...

Comment: uso o foreach para percorrer na minha tabela para obter a linha especificada na minha cláusula WHERE ... Documentos() é a minha classe com as funções de armazenar e etc ... Disseste que faço o envio do ficheiro de uma só vez ... era suposto ter mais alguma coisa?

Comment: @C-lioGarcia o problema é que tens um foreach, cujo objectivo é iterar por resultados, e depois o resto do código só é executado uma vez. Se só é suposto haver um documento, porquê o foreach?

Comment: @BluntT, usei o foreach a título de exemplo ... Este código é somente para testar ... Não me diga que o foreach causa alguma coisa?

Comment: @C-lioGarcia o foreach não vai causar problema. o comportamento do script é que podia não ser o que estavas à espera porque basicamente só o último resultado do foreach é que vai ser enviado para o browser. a maneira mais fácil de tentar perceber o que se passa é usar uma ferramenta que faça o diff entre o ficheiro que vem do browser e o original, e ver se há alguma diferença no inicio ou fim do ficheiro, por exemplo.

Comment: Percebo. Por ser teste, eu adicionei somente um registo na BD e o que acontece é que esse ficheiro armazenado em binário, quando eu faço o download (já em pdf) e tento abrir, retorna-me a mensagem que o acrobat reader não consegue abrir e que poderá não ter sido decodificado correctamente.